# React & Mobx: render (via method render()) @observable data that will be modified after the specified component is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

Please advise how to solve the following problem:

There is a component that outputs some counter:

```
@observer class MyComponent extends React.Component {    
    render() {

        const data: MyData = new MyData();    

        return <div>{data['counter']}</div>;
    }
}
```

The counter is stored in a trackable (via mobx @observable) singleton:

```
export class MyData extends ISingleton
{
    @observable data: any = {}
}
```

At some point the counter (when MyComponent is already created) the counter is set

```
let data: MyData = new MyData(); 
data['counter'] = 123;
```

But MyComponent is not redrawn, although the component seems to track variable change (via mobx @observer and @observable)

Please advise where is the error and how can it be fixed

Comment: Can you maybe make a small reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 1):

In mobx you need manipulate the state of observers within actions.

You should extend your singleton to look something like this:

```
export class MyData extends ISingleton
{
    @observable data: any = {}

    @action 
    setCounter(val: number) {
        this.data = val
    }
}
```

Then call the setCounter-Method instead of manipulating the state directly.

Please take note that as of version 6 of MobX it is discouraged to use the decorator API (see [this for more information](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Every render creates a completely fresh new `data` object, effectively resetting it. So you want to store `data` at the class instance, not inside the render. Also the data you are modifying is completely different data than the data you are rendering (that is what the `new` keyword does). Probably you want to read up a little on how objects, classes & instances work in JavaScript in general

Comment: that's the point - this data is common for some components and I don't want to duplicate it in each component via states, so I would like Mobx to track the change of the variable value and keep the rendering